# Exracting text from a webpage using requests and xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract the Overtopping ACE value on this website

https://levees.sec.usace.army.mil/#/levees/system/4305000043/system

I've tried using requests.get and then the xpath to get the value of 0.01, but my xpath always seems wrong

```
import requests
from lxml import html
pageContent=requests.get("https://levees.sec.usace.army.mil/#/levees/system/4305000043/system")
tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)
ACE=tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/ui-view/system-detail/div/two-pane-layout/div/div[1]/nld-transclude-inject/pane-left/div/div[1]/levee-system-system/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/nld-select-input/div/div/input/text()")
print(ACE)
```

What I want is for it to print 0.01

Comment: ***"my xpath always seems wrong"***: Your `xpath` is ok, but this site uses `javascript` to insert the content you want. `requests` don't execute `javascript`. Verify with **javascript OFF** in your browser and you see **nothing**.

Comment: I figured it out today. Exactly why you said that javascript ended up messing with me. So in the end I decided to use selenium. A bit slow but serviced its purpose!